# How to redirect form submit to an external URL and also open it in a new tab

Tags: forms

In D9 we have a custom form that needs to redirect the user to an external URL and also have it open in a new window/tab.

We have the external redirect working using TrustedRedirectResponse but there doesn't seem to be a way to have it open in a new tab.

What is a working solution to redirect to an external URL and also have it open in a new tab?

```
public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $url = "https://somewebsite.com";
  $response = new TrustedRedirectResponse(\Drupal\Core\Url::fromUri($url)
    ->toString());
  $metadata = $response->getCacheableMetadata();
  $metadata->setCacheMaxAge(0);
  $form_state->setResponse($response);
}
```

Comment: I think this is impossible with PHP alone. There is no HTTP response that would induce a browser to open a tab.

Comment: Thanks cilefen, that's what I suspected and explains why there is no documentation on how to achieve this.

Comment: Although there may be a way to return a page that only contains JavaScript, which contains redirect code.

Answer (score 1):

This answer indicates that you can add a formtarget attribute to the submit action in order to open it in a new tab: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/307453

That worked for me:

```
$form['actions']['submit'] = [
  '#type' => 'submit',
  '#value' => 'Search',
  '#attributes' => [
    'formtarget' => '_blank'
  ]
];

public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $response = new TrustedRedirectResponse($url);
  $metadata = $response->getCacheableMetadata();
  $metadata->setCacheMaxAge(0);
  $form_state->setResponse($response);
}
```